# CKEditor Image Links

Tags: image, hyperlink, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor in my application. I have a back-end admin section where articles can be made and edited, and a front-end where they are viewed. I want the image links to be relative to website.com/article/images.

To view the images in the editor in the backend(website.com/admin/page.php), the images need to be ../article/images/image.jpg, whereas on the frontend displaying the article they need to be article/images/image.jpg. I'm looking for the function in CKEditor that I can configure that in.

Comment: What influences do you have if images have  the same complete link in both front and backend?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: I mean in backend image link can also be http://website.com/article/images/image.jpg, why you want display relative  link?